# UPDATE and SELECT to/from the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join, sql-update

Table1:

```
BrID    HQID
------------
Br1     HQ1
HQ1     
HQ2     
Br2     HQ1
Br3     HQ2
```

Table2:

```
ID    Name        BrID    IDt2
------------------------------
11    OthName11   Br1     
22    HQName111   HQ1
33    HQName222   HQ2
44    OthName22   Br2     
55    OthName33   Br3
```

I need to UPDATE Table2.IDt2 for each row from Table1 which has HQID value but with Table2.ID connected by Table1.HQID = Table2.BrID

In other words fro the first row .

```
SELECT HQID FROM Table1 WHERE BrID = 'Br1'
SELECT ID WHERE Table2.BrID = HQID (from previous SELECT)
UPDATE Table2 SET IDt2 = ID(from previous SELECT) WHERE Table2.BrID = 'Br1' (from first SELECT)
```

This should be the result Table2:

```
ID    Name        BrID    IDt2
------------------------------
11    OthName11   Br1     22
22    HQName111   HQ1
33    HQName222   HQ2
44    OthName22   Br2     22
55    OthName33   Br3     33
```

Is it possible to make it in one UPDATE?
How else can I do this?

Comment: can you explain the relationship between the tables more preciously?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need multiple `JOIN` statements:

```
UPDATE a
SET a.IDT2 = c.ID
FROM Table2 a
JOIN Table1 b
  ON a.BRID = b.BRID
JOIN TAble2 c 
  ON b.HQID = c.BRID
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4784b/5/2)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
UPDATE A 
SET A.IDt2 = A1.ID 
FROM table2 A 
INNER JOIN table1 T1 ON A.BrID = T1.BrId 
INNER JOIN table2 A1 ON T1.HQID = A1.BrId;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write the queries as sub queries on the third query `UPDATE Table2 SET IDt2 = (SELECT ID WHERE...)` and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Check this..

```
UPDATE t2
SET    t2.IDt2 = t1.ID
FROM   table2 t2
       JOIN (
                SELECT t1.BrID,
                       t1.HQID,
                       t2.ID
                FROM   table1 t1
                       LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2
                            ON  t2.BrID = t1.HQID
            ) t1
            ON  t2.BrID = t1.BrID
```

Comment: Just an info: it would be helpful, if you could explain the answer you supply.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE  T2
SET     T2.IDt2 =  (SELECT T3.ID
                    FROM   Table1 T1 INNER JOIN
                           Table2 T3 ON T3.BrID = T1.HQID
                    WHERE  T2.BrID = T1.BrID)
FROM    Table2 T2
```